# The word order in these questions

Tags: word-order

> 1 To smoke is important to him.
>
> 1a How important to him is to smoke?

> 2 It is important to him to smoke.
>
> 2a How important to him is it to smoke?

Are 1a and 2a correct?

Comment: No, in 1a replace "to smoke" with "smoking". All 4 are probably not what a native BrE speaker would say and can be replaced by *Smoking is important to him / How important is smoking to him?*. In any case, please include the research you did before asking this question.

Comment: But is 1 correct? If 1 is correct, why is it that 1a is not?

Comment: All the examples are "syntactically valid". But they're all *non-idiomatic* (because ***smoking*** is preferred over ***to smoke*** here). AND 1a is *particularly* non-idiomatic because native speakers would almost always include pronoun ***it*** in such constructions. But obsessing over "syntactically valid" utterances is pointless if the text under consideration isn't something native speakers say anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentences (1), (1a), (2), and (2a) are all grammatically valid. None of these would be likely to be said or written by a fluent speaker, they are **not natural**. As the [comment by user  FumbleFingers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/331533/the-word-order-in-these-questions#comment627179_331533) points out, "*smoking*" would normally be used instead of "*to smoke*". In sentences (1a) and (2) as writen the use of 'to smoke": makes the word "*to*" occur twice in close succession. This feels awkward to many fluent speakers, so it would be avoided.

If a fluent speaker were to say something like (1a), the pronoun "it" would almost surely be added:

> (1b) How important to him is it to smoke?

But although this is slightly better than (1a) it is still not very natural.

I would say that (2) is somewhat more natural than (1), and (2a) is perhaps the best of all of these. But the more likely forms would be:

> (2b) Smoking is important to him.

> (2c) How important is smoking to him?